How to get control identifiers for just the context menu items or dropdown items and not the entire window?
So I am trying to automate a task in an app using pywinauto and i want to know the control identifiers of only elements inside lets say context menu or elements inside dropdown menu for ex:

I know that we have way to obtain control identifiers for a dialog by :
 app.PageSetup.print_control_identifiers()

Or The list of identifiers for the Edit control in the dialog using :
   app.PageSetup.Edit2.print_control_identifiers()


But how to go about doing this for Context menu items or dropdown items?

For backend="win32" context menus are top-level windows, so you need to search for them starting from the application object. For backend="uia" they are often children of current dialog (top level window). But it depends on the app and GUI framework implementation. What Inspect.exe shows for it?

Thanks for your comment. Inspect tool gives name property for "Vertical Tabs" button in my sample screenshot above as Vertical Tabs and LocalizedControlType as Menu Item.  I think this implies i can use .child_window(title ="Vertical Tabs", control_type =  "MenuItem") to locate it. But as you mentioned we can use children of dialog method    which should look like app.Dialog.TabsLayout.VerticalTabs.click_input()right? should this be the more efficient and better way to locate the element or the former way @VasilyRyabov ? FYI the app is OneNote and backend is "uia"

Using app.Dialog.child_window(title="Vertical Tabs", control_type="MenuItem").click_input() should be enough. Some levels after dialog could be skipped. The search at 2nd+ level is done for the whole depth.
